# C# Application Default Credentials not available

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently trying to access the cloud API and I am receiving this error:

> The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

I have already gone onto my google cloud platform account, enabled billing, created a service account, downloaded a JSON key and set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in my environment variables and have checked that it's pointing to the correct JSON key. It is pointing to my API key
'C:\Users\jade.wilson\source\repos\CloudApi\CloudApi\Services\Keys\CloudAPIKey.json'

This is the code:

```
   var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault();
   var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.ToString(), credential.ToChannelCredentials());

   var client = SpeechClient.Create(channel);

   response = await client.RecognizeAsync(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromStream(audio));
```

It is not getting past the first line. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that in the question, I'm gonna recommend an edit.

Comment: Make sure you do not have a typo in something. How are you executing your program - you have specified a path based from your home directory so normally you need to be logged in as that user to have rights to the file.

Comment: Could you tell us *how* you've set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` exactly? If that environment variable is set, I'd expect you to get a different error if the file is wrong etc. (I could be wrong on that front, mind you.) If you log `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")` on start-up, do you see the value you expect? (My guess is that you've set the environment variable for one user, but not the user running the code.) Also note that just using `var client = SpeechClient.Create();` is the simple way to use the default endpoint and default credentials.

Comment: It's definitely set as I've checked that it's been added to the enviornment variables and it's definitely in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by "I've checked that it's been added to the enviornment variables" exactly? How have you checked? If you log the result of `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")` in your code, does that show the result you expect? (I suspect it won't.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio, just close and reopen it.

It seems that if you create/alter environment variables while Visual Studio is open, the programs that you'll run/debug won't be able to see them. You have to exit Visual Studio and reenter (happened to me: VS 2019 ver. 16.7.2, Win 10 ver. 2004 - OS Build 19041.450)